# asp.net form does not retain the value on the field

Tags: asp.net

I have a form as such:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
Inherits="DataEntry_EntryForm1" EnableEventValidation="false" CodeBehind="Bio.aspx.cs" %>

    <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/site.master" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    </asp:Content>


    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="Server">

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell  >
        <asp:Label ID="lblRoomNum" runat="server" Text="Room #"  Width="100px" ></asp:Label> 
       </asp:TableCell>
      <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left">
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtRoomNum" runat="server" Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" Room # is required." ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtRoomNum"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                  </asp:TableCell>

      </asp:Table>

        <div style="width: 300px; margin: 20px 250px">
         <asp:Button ID="txtSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="txtSubmit_Click" />
       </div>

     </asp:Content>
```

I am using the same form for creating a new record as well as updating it. When I create a new record, it works fine.
When I try to update a record with data already filled in, the form does not retain that value. Instead, it retains the value that was there previously.

Is there anything wrong that I am doing?

Here is the codebehind code:

```
     protected void txtSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

          string s = txtRoomNum.Text;

      }
```

It shows the old value and not the updated code.

Comment: you mean user changes the values, hits "Submit" and after page posts back - it displays old values?

Comment: Could you show the code you use to update the database?

Comment: Where is start of your `<asp:Table>`, I see the ending tag, but not the opening tag?

Comment: And what is in your `Page_Load`? My guess is you are populating the textbox (`txtRoomNum.Text`) in `Page_Load` with the value from the database and that is overwriting your new value, because `Page_Load` fires before your click event handler does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a look at the **IsPostBack** property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        loadOldValue();
    }
}

public void loadOldValue()
{
    txtRoomNum.Text = "OLD VALUE";
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = txtRoomNum.Text;
}
```

**Explanation:** The Page_Load() function is the first thing called each time you click on your submit button. So if you load the old value in your Page_Load(), it will always have the old value.
To avoid this, use the !IsPostBack property. If the page is not a post back it will load the old value. Otherwise it will let you use the new value in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

use this to get value :

```
string s=Request.Form[txtRoomNum.UniqueID];
```

Comment: How does this address the issue of an older value being found in the control?